# Consulta select con SUM java

Tags: java, sql, jpa

necesito hacer una consulta contando el numero de horas de un campo, este es mi código.

el campo es un entero, ya que solo se guarda un numero 2,3,4 horas no se requiere que sea un tipo time.

```
public Object findBySum(Integer iduser){
    Query q =  getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM Asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN Empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser =   "+ iduser, Asistenciacapacitaciones.class)
            .setParameter("iduser", iduser);
            List count = (List) q.getResultList();
    return ((BigInteger)count.get(0)).longValue();

}
```

al hacerlo me devuelve el siguiente error,

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [ArrayRecord(
     => 23)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Asistenciacapacitaciones sql="select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM Asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN Empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser =   1")
```

por lo que veo si me trae el resultado de la consulta que es 23, y ya la probé en la unidad de persistencia, la consulta esta bien.

¿que estoy haciendo mal?, ¿o que me falta?.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ese error parece ser que tienes valores null en la llave primaria de la tabla de tu base de datos

Comment: Pero es que, en el error me muestra que si llega el iduser que es 1, no entiendo porque sale eso...

Comment: Puede ser un problema de nombres de columnas, que las tienes definidas en minúscula y la query las retorna en mayúsculas. [Mira esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14189997/5587982)  a un problema parecido al tuyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, al final la solucion fue castearlo como un objeto y pasarselo a un metodo rest que lo mostrara como un json.

```
public Object findBySum(Integer iduser) {
    Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser =   " + iduser)
            .setParameter("iduser", iduser);
    Object res = (Object) q.getSingleResult();
    return res;

}
```

El json que devuelve tiene esta pinta

```
{"type":"decimal","value":5}
```

Ya en el front era solo trabajar con ese objeto json, que ya es fácil de hacer.

Gracias por responder igualmente.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas en versiones menos recientes por defecto a menos que la eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-namespropiedad persistente se establezca en true.

Este puede ser el problema de las consultas nativas si la base de datos devuelve el nombre de la columna en mayúsculas por ejemplo: "ID"cuando lo tiene definido como minúscula "id".

Intente cambiar las definiciones de columna en las anotaciones para que coincidan con las que utiliza su base de datos o agregue la propiedad con un valor de true, revisa bien que tus columnas tengan el mismo nombre como en la base de datos.

También para que usas el `.setParameter("iduser", iduser);`  si se lo estan concatenando en dado caso debería ser así:

```
public Object findBySum(Integer iduser){
    Query q =  getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM Asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN Empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser =   "+ iduser, Asistenciacapacitaciones.class);
            List count = (List) q.getResultList();
    return ((BigInteger)count.get(0)).longValue();

}
```

o

```
public Object findBySum(Integer iduser){
    Query q =  getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM Asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN Empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser =   :iduser", Asistenciacapacitaciones.class)
            .setParameter("iduser", iduser);
            List count = (List) q.getResultList();
    return ((BigInteger)count.get(0)).longValue();

}
```

También cuando El tipo de retorno se utiliza cuando desea que el proveedor JPA construya una entidad a partir de los resultados, pero en este caso desea los datos sin procesar.

```
public Object findBySum(Integer iduser){
        Query q =  getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM Asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN Empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser =   :iduser")
                .setParameter("iduser", iduser);
                List count = (List) q.getResultList();
        return ((BigInteger)count.get(0)).longValue();

    }
```

U otra forma podria ser:

```
BigDecimal sum =(BigDecimal)em.createNativeQuery ("select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM Asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN Empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser =  ?")
.setParameter(1, iduser)
.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, revisé y están igual a la base de datos todo en minúscula, lo único en mayúscula es la primera letra de  los nombres de las tablas que al estar mapeados en java se ponen así, sin embargo probé poniendo en minúscula y tampoco, de hecho las 3 formas que compartiste ya las había intentado y me marca error, la 3a forma me marca que el iduser no se encuentra.  Encontre en un foro que como requiero sacar un valor y ya, no pusiera el Asistenciacapacitaciones.class, pero ahi me marca otro: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: Si lo casteo poniendo BigInteger.class, entonces marca otro error:

Comment: Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class java.math.BigInteger].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=BigInteger sql="select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM Asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN Empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser =   2")

Comment: Tu consulta select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM Asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN Empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser = 1 en tu base de datos si te da el resultado así tal cual no tienes que poner los nombres de tus clases si no en ese caso usarias createQuery en lugar de createNativeQuery

Comment: si, sale esto java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger

Comment: public Object findBySum(Integer iduser) {
        Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select SUM(a.cantidadhoras) FROM asistenciacapacitaciones a JOIN empleados e on e.iduser = a.iduser WHERE e.iduser =   " + iduser)
                .setParameter("iduser", iduser);
        List count = (List) q.getResultList();
        return ((BigInteger) count.get(0)).longValue();

    }